# Why is `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` consuming more battery than `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`?

Tags: android, gps

We benchmarked the amount of battery spent by a device on requesting the location every 10 minutes, that was solely connected to WiFi, under the same circumstances

- Post factory reset
- Same starting battery levels
- No extra apps installed

with the priority first set to `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` and then to `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`.

And surprisingly, the former used up the same, if not more battery than the latter. Here is the graph of battery usage:

[image]
[image]

Could someone please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

**PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY** is more likely to use GPS, and **PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY** is more likely to use WIFI & Cell tower positioning.

- `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` (~100m "block" accuracy)
- `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` (accurate as possible at the expense of battery life)

  use **setInterval(long)** and **setFastestInterval(long)** for saving battery life.

> Example:

```
private static final long INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000;
private static final long DISPLACEMENT = 100;

private LocationRequest createLocationRequest(){
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
        return mLocationRequest;
    }
```

Google describes the `LocationRequest` class here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html

Comment: I believe this answer actually doesn't answer the question